# Debian: pulseaudio sink volumes syncing?

Tags: linux, debian, audio, pulseaudio, volume

Running Debian jessie with pulseaudio, sometimes I would use `pavucontrol` to adjust volumes of different applications at varying levels. Then when I would forget about it and adjust the volume using keys mapped to `pactl set-sink-volume 1 -- -10%`.

But if the sink volume was 50% and then I set the application volume in `pavucontrol` to `100%`, forgot about it, then used `pactl set-sink-volume 1 -- -10%` the application volume would exceed 100%... and if it's an alsa container then it would make awful screeching sounds very loudly.

Is there a quick way to reset all of the applications volumes?

Comment: I have a similar issue, everytime I try to set the volume on a single sink-input it also sets the sink to that volume. `pactl set-sink-input-volume 123 100%` which is irritating because some programs are super quite and others super loud. (on the rare occasion I manage to get the sink and sink-input volumes separated, Chrome for example resets its sink-input volume every time I restart the computer, and the same method doesn't work every time even when reusing commands straight from the terminal `history` list)